# javascript: deleting tags of a selected element in a text

Tags: javascript, html, text, tags

I put a tag to a selected element in my textarea and every tag take an id. And I store the element an a table.
But, I want to delete some tags(I have to type of tag "ref" et "point"). And I try this function but, it doesn't work:

```
function deleteTag(textField, tag)
{
var scrollTop = textField.scrollTop;        //For the scroll of the text 
var start = textField.selectionStart;       //beginning of the selected text
var end = textField.selectionEnd;           //End of the selected text
var modif=textField.value.substring(start,end); //The text to modify
// Remove the tag
if(modif.match('[^<]'+tag+'id="(\\d+)">') && modif.match('</'+tag+'[>$]'))
{
    var regex;
    if(tag=="ref")
    {
         regex=new RegExp('<'+tag+' id="(\\d+)">');
         var opt=modif.match(regex)[1];
         document.getElementById("refList").remove(opt-1);
    }
    regex=new RegExp('<'+tag+'[^>]+>');
    modif=modif.replace(regex, "");
    modif=modif.replace('</'+tag+'>', "");
  }        
textField.value=textSup+modif+textInf;  //We modify the text inside the text area
textField.scrollTop=scrollTop;
}
```

And the button have this code:

```
<button onclick="deleteTag(textAreaId, 'ref')"> Effacer
```

By the way I'm beginner in javascript

Comment: Fiddle will be helpful

Comment: I use it but some times it doesn't give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
if(modif.match('[^<]'+tag+'id="(\\d+)">') && modif.match('</'+tag+'[>$]'))
```

maybe you need an extra space in the regex:

```
if(modif.match('[^<]'+tag+' id="(\\d+)">') && modif.match('</'+tag+'[>$]'))
```

Comment: No it does not work. Also, I have a problem with the id I should decrement all the id of the tags that were created after the tag that I want to delete.